# Desktop icons not showing up

Tags: desktop-icons

I'm in a new role and have never used Ubuntu before, but when I open the desktop, the icons don't show up. Other solutions I have found online have me going to settings or the terminal, but the only application I can open up is Firefox [(photo of desktop here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsIAI.jpg).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you logged in? What icons are you expecting? What version Of Ubuntu? Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu? You'll need a second computer and a USB drive: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop